# Setting of Server Side Cookie is failing - Python Tornado Framework

Tags: python-2.7, session-cookies, tornado

I am trying to set server side cookies(sessions) in client side. But it is failing.

The process is as follows:

1) Inititate a call to an API which is residing in abc.com from blog.abc.com.

2) The API from abc.com is going to return a response object to blog.abc.com.

I am getting the set_cookie in response object from the API, but in the client side it is not setting!

The following are the request and response headers from abc.com when I called the API from blog.abc.com

**Request Headers:**

```
 Host: abc.com
 Connection: keep-alive
 Accept: */*
 Origin: http://blog.abc.com
 Referer: http://blog.abc.com/
```

**Response Headers:**

```
  Connection: keep-alive
  Set-Cookie: session_token="2|1:0|10:1474371987|13:session_token|44:NDFjZjNiZjFiYjcwNDk4ZTk4NDllYmRhNmNkYzFjZTA=|f60c277db4f5f38ec31f55bc581ddcf997f38fa493276508156f983500de4b25"; expires=Wed, 21 Sep 2016 11:46:27 GMT; Path=/

  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

But in the client side (blog.abc.com), there is no cookie ("session-token").

Can anyone please help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The cookie should still be getting set correctly on abc.com, but you can't see that cookie from javascript on blog.abc.com. This is part of the same-origin policy: you can't see cookies that are set for another domain (regardless of `access-control-allow-*`). If you need this information in the client, it needs to be in the body of the response.